# Does Moulinet combo with other FS: Fencing levels?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I had a question concerning the 4th dot in fencing.

> Moulinet (••••): If your character makes a successful hit on an adversary with his sword, he may then rotate his wrist and perform a quick spiral cut with the tip of the weapon. This additional cut requires no additional roll; the cut does lethal damage to the opponent equal to your character’s Dexterity.
>
> Drawback: To perform this maneuver, the character must spend a Willpower point before he makes her initial attack roll. The Willpower does not grant him the additional +3 to 
>   attack. If the initial attack roll fails, the Willpower point is wasted and the Moulinet may not be added.

Can that be comboed with the other dots previous dots, like the 3rd dot…

> Riposte (•••):A Riposte requires an attack to be made against your character. He steps out of the way of the attack using his Dodge (i.e., her Defense, doubled). While his opponent is open, he can then make a sudden and quick attack, which is performed at a –1 penalty. 
>   However, the opponent’s Defense does not further penalize the attack roll.
>
> Drawback: If your opponent suffers any further attacks on a turn where she has used Riposte, she cannot apply her Defense against them.

…so after the character dodges and counters with riposte, they then perform the moulinet?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

It's not for nothing that Moulinet was once cited as one of the "[Five Broken Abilities of the World of Darkness](http://mythcreants.com/blog/five-broken-abilities-from-the-world-of-darkness/)." Just remember that you must spend the Willpower before you roll for the Riposte, and you'll get no extra dice for it.

Comment: However, this is specific to Moulinet because it activates on a successful hit. A number of FS abilities are *not* compatible with each other because they are each unique maneuvers (ie: requiring a separate attack).